# NXLog Windows Events and Source

Tags: event-log, nxlog

I want to upload events only from a "puppet" source, which is "Windows Logs\Application".
I guess I have to change the line `<Select Path = 'Application'> * </Select>`

How to filter source "puppet" in nxlog.conf?

```
<Input in>
    Module       im_msvistalog
    ReadFromLast TRUE
    <QueryXML>
       <QueryList>
         <Query Id='1'>
           <Select Path='Application'>*</Select>      
         </Query>
       </QueryList>
   </QueryXML>
   Exec $FileName = 'winapp.log';
   Exec $EventTime = $EventReceivedTime;   
 </Input>

<Output out1>
 Module om_udp
 Host 10.10.0.40
 Port 514
 Exec to_syslog_bsd();
</Output>

<Route 1>
Path in => out1
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

here's how i've done it :

```
<Query Id='1'>
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider[(@Name="MySrcName")]]]</Select>
</Query>
```

I found the tree path : *System > Provider > Name*
by opening the windows **event viewer**, then select your **event**, then **event properties**, then **details**.

I said that because it may be different for you based on your windows version.